# particles.js conflicting with fullpage.js, blocking text and not fully covering page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have tried to add particles.js into my website which is currently using fullpage.js. I have added the two scripts(particles.js and app.js) into my html file, and also have added  in each of the sections of my fullpage.js page. The issue that I am currently encountering is that when I test the page, the particles would take up most of the page and move my title upwards. If I scroll down into the second section of the page, the particles would disappear. I have tried fixing this by adding:

```
    body{
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        color: #37675D;
        }
    
    h{
        font-size: 80px;
        margin: 0 0 30px;
    }
    
    h1{
        font-size: 80px;    
        margin: 0 0 30px;
        font-size: 80px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .section{
        background: #ABF0D1;  
    }
    
    p{
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .container{
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow; auto;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    
    #fp-nav.fp-right{
        right: 10px;
    }
    
    #fp-nav ul li a span, .fp-slidesNav ul li a span{
        background: #37675D;
    }
    
    .responsive {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    #header{
        position:fixed;
        height: 50px;
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
        z-index:9;
        text-align:center;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 20px 0 0 0;
        top:0px;
    }
    
    
    .overlay {
        height: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
        overflow-y: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .overlay-content {
        position: relative;
        top: 25%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .overlay a {
        padding: 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 36px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .overlay .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 45px;
        font-size: 60px;
    }
    
    input[type=text], select, textarea {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        resize: vertical;
    }
    
    input[type=submit] {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-color: #45a049;
    }
    
    .funnycontainer {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .zigzag{ 
        border: none; 
        margin: auto; 
        margin-top: 5%; 
        margin-bottom: 5%; 
        height: 40px; 
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ABF0D1 25%, transparent 25%) -20px 0, 
        linear-gradient(225deg, #ABF0D1 25%, transparent 25%) -20px 0, 
        linear-gradient(315deg, #ABF0D1 25%, transparent 25%), 
        linear-gradient(45deg, #ABF0D1 25%, transparent 25%); 
        background-size: 40px 40px; 
        background-color: #37675D;
    }
    
    #particle {
        background-color: #b61924;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:0; 
    }
    
    #overlay {
        position: relative;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullpage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>  
    
    <div id="header">
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="submenu1.html">submenu1</a>
                <a href="submenu2.html">submenu2</a>
                <a href="submenu3.html">submenu3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <span style = "float: left; padding-left: 20px;  font-size: 50px; color: #37675D" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
        <img style = "float: right; padding-right: 20px;" src="images/img1.png" alt="img" width="100" height="120" class="img">
    </div>
    
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section section1">
            <div id="particles-js">
                <div class="container">
                    <h><strong>Title</strong></h>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section section2">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <hr class="zigzag">
                <p>All areas of design including, interior designers, product design, architecture, web and programme design, advertising, fashion design, stage and set design. All aspects of engineering, from mechanical to civil, and all levels of trades technicians. All aspects of the automotive industry, mechanics, sales representatives, warrant assessors, welders, auto electricians, auto-body repair specialists, finishers etc. All the electrical and electronics trades, including electronics engineers, computer engineers, computer engineers, electrical engineer, for building and construction, all the related trades including foundation construction through to roofer, glazier, plumber, jib fixers and finishers, painter, landscaper etc, also related to this is the boat building industry which would include Naval architect, boat builder, rigger, boat fitter etc. In the food and catering industries careers include butcher, cake decorator, catering manager, childcare worker, confectioners maker, diet supervisor, dietician / nutritionist, early childhood teacher, flight attendant, food packer, food technologist, food bar assistant, hospital aide, hotel housekeeper, hotel / motel manager, kitchen hand, pastry cook, quality controller, small goods manager, teacher, waiter, waitress. From fabrics dressmaker, machinist / cutter, personal presentation, sale assistant / clothing / furniture, tailor, teacher, textile designer, theatre costume designer, pattern designer, pattern cutter. ICT is used in all aspects of industrial and business life and the training in and efficient use of all computer related skills is an essential of 21st century life.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section section3">
            <div class="slide"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="img1" class="responsive"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="img2" class="responsive"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="img3" class="responsive"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="img3" class="responsive"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="section section4">
            <div class="container">
                <footer>
                    <h2>text</h2>
                    <h2>text</h2>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/particles.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            //options here
            autoScrolling:true,
            scrollHorizontally: true,
            navigation: true,
            controlArrows: false
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    }
    
    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->

Image of error:
[![An image of the error that I am having.][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lg67.png
```